# Informix java.sql.SQLException: Column (...) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, informix

The query below is working without any problems in my java based sql Editor:

```
      begin work;
create SEQUENCE if not exists zahlpaketcounter start 1;
select zahlpaketcounter.nextval as counter,*
 from (
SELECT 
firma_nr
,zahlpaket.nummer
,zahlpaket.bezeichnung
,personenkonto.kontonummer
,personenkonto.bezeichnung
,zahlbewegung.op_nr
,zahlbewegung.zahlbetrag_druck
,fibu_beleg.archiv_nr
FROM integris.zahlbewegung
join zahlpaket on zahlbewegung.zahlpaket_id=zahlpaket.zahlpaket_id
join integris.personenkonto on zahlbewegung.personenkonto_id=personenkonto.personenkonto_id
join integris.opbewegung on  zahlbewegung.opbewegung_id=opbewegung.opbewegung_id
join integris.fibu_beleg on opbewegung.fibu_beleg_id=fibu_beleg.fibu_beleg_id
join integris.firma on zahlpaket.firma_id = firma.firma_id
where 1=1
and zahlbewegung.zahlbetrag_druck >=0
order by nummer,personenkonto.kontonummer,zahlbewegung.op_nr
);
drop sequence zahlpaketcounter;
commit work;
```

when I use in it java:

```
        sql=getTextResource(this,"sql/getZahlläufe.sql");
        fibustmt.execute(sql);
```

the execute method fails with:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Column (zahlpaketcounter) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
```

Why? Any Ideas?

Comment: I notice it says `..Column  not..` (with 2 spaces) indicating that it's looking for a column with no name?  I've no idea how or why though, but it might be a clue.

Comment: Oh it was lost in copy and paste: the column stated is zahlpaketcounter. I change the title tomorrow when I get back to the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not possible to use multiple statements with execute(). You should use addBatch() and executeBatch() but not with a SELECT.
It works with 3 execute().

```
String sqlQ="create SEQUENCE if not exists zahlpaketcounter start 1";
PreparedStatement pstmt = cnx.prepareStatement();
pstmt.execute();
sqlQ="SELECT ...";
pstmt = cnx.prepareStatement();
pstmt.execute();
sqlQ="drop SEQUENCE if exists zahlpaketcounter";
pstmt = cnx.prepareStatement();
pstmt.execute();
```